# How to determine if condition_variable::wait_for timed out

Tags: multithreading, c++11, timeout, condition-variable

I have a class which allows to wait on a condition_variable taking care of the spurious wake ups. Following is the code:

**Code:**

```
// CondVarWrapper.hpp
#pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

class CondVarWrapper {
public:
    void Signal() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> unique_lock(mutex);
        cond_var_signalled = true;
        unique_lock.unlock();
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }

    // TODO: WaitFor needs to return false if timed out waiting
    bool WaitFor(const std::chrono::seconds timeout) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> unique_lock(mutex);
        bool timed_out = false;
        // How to determine if wait_for timed out ?
        cond_var.wait_for(unique_lock, timeout, [this] {
            return cond_var_signalled;
        });
        cond_var_signalled = false;
        return timed_out;
    }

    void Wait() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> unique_lock(mutex);
        cond_var.wait(unique_lock, [this] {
            return cond_var_signalled;
        });
        cond_var_signalled = false;
    }

private:
    bool cond_var_signalled = false;
    std::mutex  mutex;
    std::condition_variable cond_var;
};

// main.cpp
#include "CondVarWrapper.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

int main() {
   CondVarWrapper cond_var_wrapper;

   std::thread my_thread = std::thread([&cond_var_wrapper]{
       std::cout << "Thread started" << std::endl;
        if (cond_var_wrapper.WaitFor(std::chrono::seconds(1))) {
            std::cout << "Wait ended before timeout" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Timed out waiting" << std::endl;
        }
    });

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(6));
   // Uncomment following line to see the timeout working
   cond_var_wrapper.Signal();
   my_thread.join();
}
```

**Question:**
In the method `WaitFor`, I need to determine if `cond_var` timed out waiting? How do I do that? `WaitFor` should return false when it timed out waiting else it should return true. Is that possible?
I see [cv_status](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/cv_status) explained on *cppreference* but struggling to find a good expample of how to use it.

Comment: Hint: What would be the value of `cond_var_signalled` immediately after `cond_var.wait_for(...)` returns because `Signal()` was called? And, what would be the value of the same variable immediately after `cond_var.wait_for(...)` returned because of a timeout?

Comment: Yes. I know that trick. I was looking for more sure way from the method `wait_for` or [wait_until](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any/wait_until). The reason is that if I have priority based approach for more than 2 threads waiting on the condition_variable then just a boolean way of indicating wont help. Right?

Comment: Maybe you should say more about what you really are trying to achieve. As it is, your question sounds a bit like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). For the case where `Wait()` returns before the `Signal()` is given, can you explain why it is important for your application to know the difference between it happening because of a timeout or, it happening for some other reason? Also, are you saying that you intend to have two threads waiting for the same condition _at different priorities?_ What is the reason for that?